# Getting a 'Request failed with status code:404' when trying to access zomato search (axios)

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I have just started out with learning react-native and stuck with an issue.

my aim is to:
1- search for restaurants in my city using the search bar by entering key words.
2- i have got the API key
3- used axios
4- got the base URL

now when i search for a key word on my emulator screen it says error and doesn't return any results.

i have attached the codes from 2 screens and also the screenshot of the emulator screen.
please do help me out!

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL:'https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search',
    headers:{
        Authorization : 'Bearer b7510cd6146de7b9b81e17ddb7e0122b'
    }
});
```

and the search screen code

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View,Text,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import SearchBar from '../components/searchBar';
import zomato from '../api/zomato';

const searchScreen = ()=>{
    const [term,setTerm] = useState('');
    const [results,setResults] = useState([]);
    const searchAPI = async () =>{
      const response = await zomato.get('/',{
        params:{
            count:15,
            q:term,
            entity_id:4
            
        }
      });
      setResults(response.data.restaurants);
    };
    return (
    <View>
        <SearchBar 
        term ={term} 
        onChangeTerm = {setTerm}
        onTermSubmit = {searchAPI}
        />
        <Text>
            Search Screen
        </Text>
        <Text>we found {results.length} results</Text>
    </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default searchScreen;
```

[image: the emulator screen]

Answer (score 0):

The error 404 displayed because you are sending an invalid URL

In your Axios instance, you are setting your base path as

```
https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search
```

When you call that instance, you are appending your base path with `"/search"` as below,

```
await api.get('/search', { params: { count: 15, q: term, entity_id: 4 } })
```

Now your final URL looks like this

```
https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search/search?.....
```

To fix this you can remove `/search` from Axios instance or call your axios instance `api.get('/', { params: { count: 15, q: term, entity_id: 4 } })`

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: hey! thank you soo  much. i tried that too, but the error still persists and i dont know wher i have been going wrong. I have taken the exact URl's and the parameters as given in the zomato API page. i have made the changes that you suggested too. @SDushan

Comment: @PrajwalKumarss is that same error? if so could you update your question with updated code then I might be able to help you.

Comment: yes sir! i have updated the question as suggested and the error now is ' possible unhandled promise rejection' error-'request failed with status code 404' @SDushan

Comment: @PrajwalKumarss header should be something like this ```'user-key': 'b7510cd6146de7b9b81e17ddb7e0122b'``` according to their documentation

Comment: you mean instead of authorization it should be user-key? @SDushan

Comment: @PrajwalKumarss yes. try their official documentation - https://developers.zomato.com/documentation#!/restaurant/search

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210439/discussion-between-prajwal-kumar-ss-and-sdushan).

Comment: Hey, i have the same problem. it works on real device but on virtual device it's not working. i think it 's related to axios and https requests